# ¿Como ver formularios web de Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, formularios, oracleforms

Estoy aprendiendo Oracle Forms instale la versión **Oracle Developer Suite 10g** pero no puedo visualizar dichos formularios web, según leí es porque ya no dan soportes NPAPI, pero en todo video que pongo usan el Chrome para los ejemplo.

Gracias de antemano, no puedo explicarme muy bien ya que soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Tiene que ser Oracle 10g? Posiblemente (no lo sé, sufrí Forms 6i) esté dependiendo de extensiones en el navegador que ya no se pueden usar (porque deben instalarse de cierta forma, que es a lo que se refiere con NPAPI). Seguramente esto está resuelto en versiones posteriores de Forms. Algunos [dicen](https://pitss.com/us/2020/08/13/how-to-run-oracle-forms-using-forms-standalone-launcher/) que tienes que usar Java Web Start para ejecutar los Forms.

Comment: Gracias,
voy a indagar sobre ese tema [**Java Web Start**] para ver que puedo hacer.